# Diagnolization of a matrix in R3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm stuck on this problem and I need help, any kind of help would do.

So i'm supposed to find a basis for $R^3$ which consists of the eigenvectors for $A$ and a matrix $M$ so that

$M^{-1}AM=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1}&0&0\\0&\lambda_{2}&0\\0&0&\lambda_{3}\end{bmatrix}$

I'm know that $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&9&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

I've found out that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $A$ is $\lambda_{values}={-3, 0 ,3}$ which gives us that the eigenvectors is equals to $\lambda_{vectors}=v_{1}=(0, 0, 1), v_{2}=(9, 3, 1) , v_{3}=(9, -3,1)$

which should give us the matrix $M=\begin{bmatrix}0&9&9\\0&3&-3\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$

and this should give us that $$M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{9}&0&1\\\frac{1}{18}&\frac{1}{6}&0\\\frac{1}{18}&-\frac{1}{6}&0\end{bmatrix}$$

this is where I knew i've done something wrong, since I cannot get

$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1}&0&0\\0&\lambda_{2}&0\\0&0&\lambda_{3}\end{bmatrix}$

with the values of $M$, $A$ and $M^{-1}$

Comment: First off, you need to have the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in corresponding order. So with that $M$, it would have to be $\lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = 3, \lambda_3 = -3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps that you computed $M.A.M^{-1}$. You should have computed $M^{-1}.A.M$.

Comment: oh snap, you're right. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @user8700908 If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @uset8700909 It loojs as if you've already done it.